# Attach Pandas Dataframe as .csv in email Without using .to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a pandas data frame that I want to send out as a .csv file in an email attachment. So right now when I use df.to_csv() the file is downloaded every time.

I do not want to save the file in the system and instead just want to pass it straight as a .csv file. Is there a way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(output of sqlquery) # this data is dataframe output of a sql query. 

def send_email(sender, recipient, aws_region, subject, df):

client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=aws_region)

BODY_TEXT = "Hello,\r\nPlease find the attached file."
BODY_HTML = """\
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>Please find the attached file.</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['From'] = sender
print(msg['From'])
msg['To'] = recipient
msg['Subject'] = 'TOI Order Alert'

# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "UTF-8"

msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)


# Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
msg_body.attach(textpart)
msg_body.attach(htmlpart)





# # Define the attachment part and encode it using MIMEApplication.
att = MIMEApplication(df.to_csv('test.csv'))
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='+ 'test.csv')

# Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed
# parent container.
msg.attach(msg_body)

# Add the attachment to the parent container.
msg.attach(att)



#Provide the contents of the email.
response = client.send_raw_email(
        Source=msg['From'],
        Destinations=[
            msg['To']
        ],
        RawMessage={
            'Data':msg.as_string(),
        }
    )
```

Comment: Generally, when I need to do this, I do via saving the attachment as tempfile and ya it will be automatically deleted when it's score is finished.
You can look at the documentation. Evaluate once, whether it fits your requirement or not.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: @mohit I am trying to send the file via ses and I’m breaching the 10mb limit. Any ideas on how I can still send this or compress the file?

Comment: You can compress it And try sending it, but better would be to store it in S3 and give a public or pre-signed, time-limited URL in the email.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following

```
import io

s_buf = io.StringIO() 
df.to_csv(s_buf)
byte_buf = s_buf.encode()
```

And pass in the byte buffer

Comment: Why is that? That still forces me to save the df to my local database. I am trying to not do this.

Comment: You want to avoid generating a csv on the local file system? If that is the case, the StringIO will create an in memory buffer containing the csv file. Then you can send it along any octet-stream

Comment: Got it, so my new code is:

    s_buf = io.BytesIO()
    df.to_csv(s_buf)

    # # Define the attachment part and encode it using MIMEApplication.
    att = MIMEApplication(EXPORTERS['dataframe.csv'](df)) 
    att= MIMEApplication(s_buf)

Unfortunately, I still receive a failing message:

  "errorMessage": "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",

Comment: I've updated my answer and converted the string to a byte like object.

Comment: New Error:


"errorMessage": "encoding without a string argument",

Comment: Would I pass the byte_buf into the MIMEApplication?